# Program in Perl that reads from file, finds a line containing specific character and prints them. × 22510

Tags: perl

I have been learning Perl for a few days and I am completely new.

The code is supposed to read from a big file and if a line contains "warning" it should store it and print it on a new line and also count the number of appearances of each type of warning. There are different types of warnings in the file e.g "warning GR145" or "warning GT10" etc.

So I want to print something like

```
Warning GR145 14 warnings
Warning GT10  12 warnings
```

and so on

The problem is that when I run it, it doesnt print the whole list of warnings.
I will appreciate your help. Here is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @warnings;

open (my $file, '<', 'Warnings.txt') or die $!;

while (my $line = <$file>)  {
  if($line =~ /warning ([a-zA-Z0-9]*):/) {
    push (@warnings, $line);
    print $1 ,"\n";
  }
}

close $file;
```

Comment: show us some sample warnings message which are not coming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a hash array, a mapping from warning string to occurrence count.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %warnings = {};

open (my $file, '<', 'Warnings.txt') or die $!;
while (my $line = <$file>)  {
    if ($line =~ /warning ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\:.*/) {
        ++$warnings{$1};
    }
}
close $file;

foreach $w (keys %warnings) {
    print $w, ": ", $warnings{$w}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: i think in the foreach loop, you wanted to put keys%warnings ?

Comment: Hi, thanks everyone. It works now, just had to be keys%warnings.                    I tried the following as well                                             while ( my ($key, $value) = each(%warnings) ) {
        print "$key => $value\n";
    }                                                                          and works as well

Comment: @Guru corrected. The `($key, $value)` solution is even better.

Answer (score 1):

You are using case sensitive matching in your `if` statement. Try adding a `/i`:

`if($line =~ /warning ([a-z0-9]*):/i)`

**EDIT:** I misread the actual question, so this answer could be ignored...